# How to use javascript variable to get a rails url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an image link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#user-image-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<%= image.id %>"><img class="user-photo" src="<%= image.picture.medium.url %>" alt="" /></a>
```

and a modal that looks like this:

```
  <div id="user-image-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="user-image" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When the image link is clicked I want to open a larger version of the image. The url of the image is obtained from a carrierwave helper `UserImage.find(id).picture.large.url`.

My js.erb file:

```
  $('#user-image-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var link = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var photo = link.data('id')
    var modal = $(this)

    // What comes next?
  })
```

I need to set the src attribute in the img tag of the modal with `UserImage.find(photo).picture.large.url`. The photo variable corresponds to the id of the `UserImage` record. How can I use the photo variable to get the correct url. I don't think I can use the photo variable inside erb tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the large picture url to the link as a data attribute, like it is done with the `id` attribute. Then (on click) get the url and do whatever you want.

```
<a href="#user-image-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-url="<%= image.picture.large.url %>">
  <img class="user-photo" src="<%= image.picture.medium.url %>" alt="" />
</a>

$('#user-image-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var link = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var imgSrc = link.data('url');
  var modal = $(this);

  modal.find(".modal-body img").attr('src', imgSrc);
})
```

Another way is to send an AJAX query with the given `id` to get the picture.